# Choose the right strategy to divide two values

Tags: vhdl, quartus, arithmetic-division

**Info:**
After getting some comments and already one answer, I decided to rewrite this question to better fit into this site.

I had a problem where I needed to downsize a 12 bit value to an 8 bit value. Unfortunately I have overlooked that I simply can use shifting to achieve that.

Based on the original thoughts there are still questions left:

1. The answer to this question mentions that there is a better way to divide by use multiplication. - Since there exists an IP component to divide and you can find different strategies to do a "real" division, I wonder if there are cases where it's still better (or at least acceptable) to use one of these methods.
2. The different methods of "real" division that I know of are:

- Use the / operator from the numeric_std library. (Would be my favourite)
- Use the Quartus IP component for division.
- Use some kind of manual implemention like mentioned [here](https://surf-vhdl.com/how-to-implement-division-in-vhdl/).

What are the possible pitfalls of these methods? Using the simple division operator '/' is attractive and using a premade IP component too. How are they different on the real hardware level when we think of timing or other things?

Comment: Since you're dividing by a power of 2, there's a simpler answer.

Comment: Taking the most significant 8 bits could work for dividing by 16. Assuming the camera even outputs full range. If it outputs limited range then you want to divide by something else than 16 and want to apply an offset. What does the camera output?

Comment: Bit shifting maybe? Right shift by 1 bit to divide by 2, for example.

Comment: when we want to go from 12 bit to 4 bit, we divide by 256 = 8 bit shift

Comment: generally, multiplication by a reciprocal is quicker than division, especially if you choose a reciprocal with a very limited number of bits

Comment: You are all right! My divider of 273 came from a mistake I made before and still had in my mind. Of course the divider to 4 bit is still a power of 2.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EE but about binary number manipulation i.e. it is a math question.

Comment: It's not a simple math question because I'm additionally asking about the side effects of different strategies to divide a value.

Comment: @TimSch The question of which to use (and I'm guessing from "IP" that you may be talking about hardware implementations, not software) isn't a trivial matter. I've spent many weeks experimenting with both RTL level division (whole words at a time down to serial clocked) and multiplication by the inverse (which itself takes substantial hardware.) And all I can say is that when I do the best I can for both approaches, the division method comes out fractionally better from a resource perspective. But I'd be open to someone more creative proving that wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to multiply or divide by any power of 2, including going down from 12 bits to 4 bits, then it's a simple bit shift.

However, multiplication is generally easier than division. Think multiplying by a reciprocal, than dividing.

If you want finer control than just factors of two, then adding a shifted version of the input to the input with one adder will get you a cheap and fast multiplier by for example, these following fractions, b0.11 = d0.75, b0.101 = d0.625, b0.1001 = d0.5625.

I'll let you tabulate all the fractions you can manage with just 3 bits set in the multiplication word, that can be implemented with 2 adders.